# How should I compile my java project targeting Java SE 8?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, java-8, jvm, launch4j

I have a Java Project (an application to play connect 4) and I want to turn it into an executable file. I created this project in VsCode, and I am using the Java Language Server (see details below). I extracted the `.jar` file, and used Launch4J to turn it into an executable, and when I run it, I get an error message (see below).
I researched the problem, and it seems that I need to compile my code targeting Java SE 8 rather than 17 (I have 17 currently installed). Could anyone explain to me how I should do this, or is there anything else I'm doing wrong?

The project has multiple files. I'm not sure if this is relevant, but the project has no external dependencies, although it does use `javax.swing`, `javax.sound`, and `java.awt` (as well as java.io.File, java.io.IOException, and java.util.Random, but I'm pretty sure those are irrelevant).

I have eclipse installed if it's necessary, but I only installed it today, and have no experience using it at all. The JDK I am using is (I believe) version `1.8.0_321`. (At least this is what I get when I type in `java -version`.)
The Java compiler version is `javac 17.0.2`

When I try to run the executable generated by Launch4J, I this is the error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.65535), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

And the popup error:

```
Java Virtual Machine Launcher  
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again.
```

Here are the Settings I used in Launch4J:

`Output File: C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Coding\Java Connect 4 v.2\Connect 4.exe`
`Jar: C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Coding\Java\Java Connect 4 v.2\Java Connect 4 v.2.jar`
`Don't wrap the jar, launch only: NOT ticked`
`Wrapper Manifest: none`
`Change dir: .`
`Command Line args: none`
`Process priority: Normal`
`Both Options NOT ticked`
`Min JRE version: 1.2.0, Prefer public JRE, but use JDK runtime if newer`
`Max JRE version: none, First 64-bit, then 32-bit.` (This was the default.)
All other settings are default.

Comment: [`javac`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/javac.html) has an option `--target` to compile to an earlier version (there is a `--source` too). Fortunately no dependencies (or you would have to swith to older versions). I hope you did not use too new features.

Comment: Since you even used `--enable-preview`, it’s rather unlikely that you can compile your code for Java 8. Maybe, you’re better off bundling your application with JDK 17 using `jlink`, rather than wrapping it with Launch4J.

Comment: Thanks @Holger! That worked and it's all up and running now. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Holger has answered this question. The answer to the problem was to ship a custom JRE image with the application with the help of JLink. That way it can be used regardless of the local version of JRE.

Answer (score 0):

- Download the latest [Java JDK version as .exe file (“x64 Installer”)](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk17-windows) and install by clicking on the .jar file.
- Now the server should start again

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood the question. The question has now been answered by @Holger. I wasn't worried about the JDK, I was having trouble with the portability of my application. This was fixed by shipping a custom JRE image with the application with the help of JLink.